# Parameter expansion on multiple variables

Tags: shell, posix

Parameter expansion on a single variable works as expected. But how to expand
parameters that comprise several variables? Example:

```
#!/bin/sh

foo=/lorem/ipsum; bar=dolor/sit

tmp="$foo/$bar"
printf '%s\n' "${tmp%/*}"
```

How to run this parameter expansion without the need of the temporary variable?

Comment: you introduce a '/' with the $tmp variable; it would need to be included, I assume?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, indeed.

Comment: What is the problem? What output are you getting and what do you expect? You should be able to use as many variables as you want within double-quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expansion allows for only the one variable, necessitating the temp var. However, if this is the exact use case, dirname may work for you, since it does pretty much exactly the same thing as %/*:

```
$ foo=/lorem/ipsum; bar=dolor/sit
$ dirname $foo/$bar
/lorem/ipsum/dolor
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one ... workaround ... that does not set the temporary variable in the *current* shell:

```
foo=/lorem/ipsum; bar=dolor/sit
(tmp="$foo/$bar"; printf '%s\n' "${tmp%/*}")
```

Comment: It's contained in a shell script, so it's not a problem that the variable is there. My intention was to have a cleaner code base and reduce the number of unnecessary variables.